# How can I make the lines to enter on a new line on auto as I write across on Vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The code in Vscode is not entering a new line on auto as I write across. It just keeps going sideways making it hard to see all the code.

[image]

Comment: press `Alt+Z` key, there is a setting that controls the start Word Wrap on File Open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `View` then enable `Word wrap`.